# Alterar valor de variavel global Jquery e usar em PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Caros, tenho um codigo que exibe um dialog com uma tabela, onde após a seleção do item, este é enviado para um campo input, via ajax. Preciso usar este valor em uma função php na mesma pagina, para que outro dialog exiba uma tabela com base no dado deste input. Estive analisando o uso de uma variavel global jquery, porém, não estou conseguindo fazer com que essa variavel receba o valor indicado no input para que possa usar futuramente. Segue o codigo que utilizo:

Javascript:

```
var cgc;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 700,                
            open: function (event, ui) { 
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none"); 
            }
        });
        $(".opener").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            var nameD = $(this).attr("id");
            var toRemove = 'opener';
            var idDialog = "#dialog" + nameD.replace(toRemove, '');
            $(idDialog).dialog("open");
        });
        $(".botao").click(function () {
            $(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });

    $(".botao").click(function () {
        getValueUsingClass(
            $(this).attr("id")
        );
    });

    function getValueUsingClass (id) {
        var chkArray = [];
        $(".chk:checked").each(function () {
            chkArray.push(
                $(this).val()
            );
        });
        var name = id;
        var toRemove = 'bt';
        var id = name.replace(toRemove, '');
        var val_id = [];

        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            val_id.push(
                $(this).attr("id")
            );
        }); 

        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join('') + "";
        var val_id2;
        val_id2 = val_id.join('') + "";

        if (selected.length > 1) {
            if (chkArray.length > 1) {
                alert("Selecione um campo");
                $('input[id=' + id + ']').val("");
            } else {
                $('input[id=' + id + ']').val(selected);

                /* Configura a requisição AJAX */
                if(id=='Cliente') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'dados_pedido.php', /* URL que será chamada */ 
                        type : 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */ 
                        data: 'CODIGO=' + $('#Cliente').val(), /* dado que será enviado via POST */
                        dataType: 'json', /* Tipo de transmissão */
                        success: function (data) {
                            if(data.sucesso == 1) {
                                $('#codigocli').val(data.codigo);
                                $('#nomecli').val(data.nomecli);
                                $('#cnpjcli').val(data.cnpjcli);
                                $('#transpcli').val(data.transpcli);
                                $('#PagCli').val(data.PagCli);
                                cgc = data.cnpjcli;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
                return false; 
            }
        } else {
            alert("Nenhuma dado selecionado");
        }
    };
});
```

HTML e PHP:

```
<a href="#dialogPed3" id="openerPed3" class="opener">
    <img src="../../images/lupa.png" id="lupa3" width="16" height="16" alt = "Add"/>
</a>
<div id="dialogPed3" class="dialog">
    <?php 
        echo "teste"."<script>document.write(cgc);</script>";
    ?>
</div>
```

No inicio do codigo jquery existe uma variavel cgc declarada, caso eu coloque um valor de imediato, tipo var cgc=123, este é exibido normalmente no echo do php, porém quando seu valor é alterado dentro do "$(document).ready(function(){" essa  nada acontece, o valor continua sendo 123.

Bom não sei se ajuda mas vou explicar o objetivo.Na minha pagina, em um determinado campo, existe um botao que exibe um dialog com uma tabela, porem essa tabela é baseada no valor que esta inserido no input #cnpjcli, porém nao encontrei uma maneira de passar esse valor para o php no momento em que chamo a funçao, o q estou tentando fazer é usar o recurso document.write(cgc); para armazenar em uma variavel php e assim passar para a função php. Caso tenha alguma outra forma de pegar o valor do input e passar para a função,tb ira ajudar.

Comment: como e onde ela recebe outro valor? no seu código ela só aparece na declaração e no momento da escrita...

Comment: Tem um bom curso AJAX no W3C. A primeira linha e intersssante:

Comment: Opa, desculpe, esqueci de colocar o local de atribuição do cgc, acabei de atualizar o código.Eu preciso que ele receba um valor oriundo de uma consulta ajax.

Comment: Toda vez que você deixa de indentar uma linha de codigo, Deus mata um gatinho. Por favor, pense nos gatinhos.

Comment: Nesse caso já conferiu o console pra ver se ele está te dando o retorno?

Comment: @Renan o.O Deus malvado esse ein.

Comment: kkk desculpe pela bagunça do codigo, vou me atentar e corrigir os proximos.

Comment: Se uso um alert(cgc); após a atribuição, este exibe o valor correto, porém não aparece quando chamado no echo "<script>document.write(cgc);</script>";

Comment: @Thiago já tive problema parecido e não lembro como resolvi, mas se não me engano a variável global não vai ser afetada por você atribuir um valor a ela dentro do success

Comment: Estou atribuindo dentro do success pois preciso do valor do campo #cnpjcli, tentei atribuir o valor fora com a linha cgc = $('#cnpjcli').val() e tb nao deu certo.

Comment: @Thiago achei uma solução aqui de como acessar ela, só vou fazer o teste pra ter certeza e respondo a sua pergunta

Comment: O principal problema esta sendo para enviar esta variavel para o php com o "<script>document.write(cgc);</script>"

Comment: Concatenar string vazia com o retorno da função `join` de `array` é redundante, ok?

Comment: @Thiago da uma olhada na parte de variaveis globais, não consegui fazer um exemplo aqui... https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guia/Valores,_Vari%C3%A1veis_e_Literais

Comment: Outra coisa: `$(document).ready(function () {/* .. SNIP .. */ })` e `$(function () { /* .. SNIP .. */})` são exatamente a mesma coisa. Você pode eliminar um dos dois para facilitar sua vida.

Comment: @Thiago sabe a diferença entre client-side e server-side? Ou seja, que a variável JavaScript corre no lado do cliente e não servidor.

Comment: Outra dica, Thiago, em vez de ficar esclarecendo e colocando código aqui nos comentários, prefira [edit] a pergunta para consolidar todo o problema lá. Assim ninguém tem que ficar lendo isto tudo para entender o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago, esta variável não é uma variável "global" por assim dizer, ela está definida dentro do escopo do jquery e do seu script, porém quando a página é recarregada, ou sofre alguma mudança na qual o código precise ser recarregado, ela é perdida.

Considere o uso de cookies [Neste site](http://lucasmoreira.com.br/2013/04/13/criar-ler-e-apagar-cookies-usando-jquery/) ou então o uso do LocalStorage [aqui neste outro site](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/armazenando-informacoes-no-computador-do-visitante-com-localstorage-e-sessionstorage/) para que o valor da variável não seja perdido ao recarregar a página.

Answer (score 0):

Vasta você declarar um `input type="hidden"` e colocar um `id="xxxx" value="";`

No script *jquery* vc define o valor para o *input* `$('#xxxx').val(300);`

nesse caso no formulário que tah o input eh como se você digitasse 300 nele.

O *xxxx* pode ser qualquer outro nome que você designar